# Leaflet extension: "this.callInitHooks is not a function"

Tags: leaflet, plugins, leaflet-plugins

I am trying to develop a leaflet function but I am getting this error which I am having trouble understanding. This is my plugin code thus far:

```
L.Spotlight = L.Class.extend({

    options: {
        width: 1,
        height: 1
    },

    initialize: function(name, options) {
        this.name = name;
        L.setOptions(this, options);
    }

});
```

And this is the code that calls it:

```
var mySpotlight = L.Spotlight("aaa", {
    width: 1,
    height: 1
});
```

I get this error when trying to initialize `mySpotlight`:

```
this.callInitHooks is not a function
```

I'm having a hard time understanding this because it seems like other plugin source code that I look at behaves the same way, for example, [this one](https://github.com/jdfergason/Leaflet.Ellipse/blob/master/l.ellipse.js):

```
L.Ellipse = L.Path.extend({

    options: {
        fill: true,
        startAngle: 0,
        endAngle: 359.9
    },

    initialize: function (latlng, radii, tilt, options) {

        L.setOptions(this, options);
        this._latlng = L.latLng(latlng);

        if (tilt) {
            this._tiltDeg = tilt;
        } else {
            this._tiltDeg = 0;
        }

        if (radii) {
            this._mRadiusX = radii[0];
            this._mRadiusY = radii[1];
        }
    },

    ...

});
```

Comment: I have rolled back the second question that you added. If an answer provides a solution to a question and you then want to ask another simply accept the answer and ask a new separate question.

Comment: Why did you roll it back? I didn't ask a second question, I provided more info than what the answer provided which was related to the first.

Comment: In that case you should provide it as a self-answer.  I mis-identified it as a new question but I think rolling back remains appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`L.Spotlight` is object, so you have to create new instance:

```
var mySpotlight = new L.Spotlight("aaa", {
    width: 1,
    height: 1
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer. Using this I was able to figure out more about how Leaflet uses factory functions and I will add this to my original post.

Answer (score 1):

@TomazicM answered the initial question but with that knowledge I took it a bit further.

I wanted to be able to call a function to return my extended object, the same way one calls any standard object (e.g. `var map = L.map(...)`, `var myGeoJSON = L.geoJSON(...)`, etc.).

The way to do this is by also declaring a factory function like so:

```
L.Spotlight = L.Class.extend({

    options: {
        highlightStyle: 1,
        spotlightShape: 1,
        spotlightStyle: 1,
        targetLayer: 1
    },

    initialize: function(name, options) {
        this.name = name;
        L.setOptions(this, options);
    }

});

L.spotlight = function(name, options) {
    return new L.Spotlight(name, options);
};
```

(as per the [docs](https://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-1-classes.html) - scroll down to "Factories"). Now I can initialize a `Spotlight` object two different ways:

```
var mySpotlight = new L.Spotlight("aaa", {
    highlightStyle: 1,
    spotlightShape: 2,
    spotlightStyle: 3,
    targetLayer: 4
});

var mySpotlight2 = L.spotlight("aaa", {
    highlightStyle: 1,
    spotlightShape: 2,
    spotlightStyle: 3,
    targetLayer: 4
});
```